# Type 'UIScrollView' does not conform to protocol 'ESExtensionsProvider'

Tags: swift, pull-to-refresh

im using eggswift, but got this error, does someone faced it?
When im using macbook, everything ok, but when im coding in macMini m1, run pod then this error appear

```
public protocol ESExtensionsProvider: class {
    associatedtype CompatibleType
    var es: CompatibleType { get }
}

extension ESExtensionsProvider {
    /// A proxy which hosts reactive extensions for `self`.
    public var es: ES<Self> {
        return ES(self)
    }

}

public struct ES<Base> {
    public let base: Base
    
    // Construct a proxy.
    //
    // - parameters:
    //   - base: The object to be proxied.
    fileprivate init(_ base: Base) {
        self.base = base
    }
}

 
extension UIScrollView: ESExtensionsProvider {
}
```

[image]

Im tried to clear cache, re-installed pod, clean build folder,.. but still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found other lib has associatedtype CompatibleType, so just change  CompatibleType to other name -> work

Comment: changed  CompatibleType name to another. it worked for me thanks